# Access. Как вызвать пользовательскую функцию?

Tags: access

В базе данных Access создал макрос на VBA. Когда функция вызывается из запроса, выполняющегося в среде Access, всё прекрасно. Но когда я использую эту функцию в запросе, выполняющемся из моей программы, получаю исключение:

```
Неопределенная функция 'Foo' в выражении.
```

Доступ к БД осуществляю через OleDBConnection (.NET).

Есть способы выполнить пользовательский макрос из внешнего запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только если открыть акцесс и выполнять запрос через него (методами application, например). В остальных случаях Jet их просто не увидит.